# Add React component in window

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to make a `Toast` component and add it in `window`, so I can make a toast when I call

```
t = new window.Toast("message","info")
t.render()
```

I make my `Toast` with `Material UI` like this:

```js
import { Alert, Snackbar } from '@mui/material';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

const ToastComponent = (message: string, type: 'info' | 'success' | 'warning' | 'error') => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);

    const handleClose = (event?: React.SyntheticEvent | Event, reason?: string) => {
        setOpen(false);
    };

    const component = (
        <Snackbar
            open={open}
            autoHideDuration={5000}
            anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'center' }}
            onClose={handleClose}
        >
            <Alert severity={type} sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
                {message}
            </Alert>
        </Snackbar>
    );

    return component;
};

export default class Toast {
    public container: HTMLElement;
    public component: JSX.Element;

    public constructor(message: string, type: 'info' | 'success' | 'warning' | 'error') {
        this.container = document.createElement('div');
        this.component = ToastComponent(message, type);
    }

    public destroy() {
        const rootContainer = document.getElementById('root') as HTMLDivElement;
        rootContainer.removeChild(this.container);
    }

    public render() {
        const rootContainer = document.getElementById('root') as HTMLDivElement;
        rootContainer.appendChild(this.container);
        const root = createRoot(this.container);
        root.render(this.component);
    }
}
```

And here is my `index.ts`

```js
import Toast from './Toast';

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
(<any>window).Toast = Toast;
```

After rollup, I call `toast = new window.Toast("message","info")` in Chrome's console.

I got an [error](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=321): `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

How can I meet my needs while still using the function component and hooks when I add the component in window?

Answer (score 0):

You’re trying to use a hook inside a class component.
Hooks can only be used inside function components.

Use `export default const Toast` instead of `export default class Toast`